# Python - Natural language processing NLTK/RE deletes spaces between words

Tags: regex, nltk, vectorization, tokenize

I am trying to normalize a text and the code deletes the spaces between words. When running the code

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk as nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('punkt')
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame



corpus =['The sky is blue and beautiful.','Love this blue and beautiful sky!','The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.']
labels=['weather','weather','animals']

corpus = np.array(corpus)
corpus_df = pd.DataFrame({'Document': corpus, 'Category': labels})
corpus_df =  corpus_df[["Document","Category"]]
print(corpus_df)


wpt = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer()
stop_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("english")
def normalize_document(doc):
    #lowercase and remove special characters/whitespace
    doc = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]',' ',doc,re.I|re.A)
    doc = doc.lower()
    doc = doc.strip()
    #tokenise document
    tokens=wpt.tokenize(doc)
    #filter stopwords out of the document
    filtered_tokens=[token for token in tokens if token not in stop_words]
    #recreate document from filtered tokens
    doc=''.join(filtered_tokens)
    return doc
normalize_corpus=np.vectorize(normalize_document)
norm_corpus=normalize_corpus(corpus_df)
```

I am receiving for

```
norm_corpus= array([['skybluebeautiful', 'weather'],
       ['lovebluebeautifulsky', 'weather'],
       ['quickbrownfoxjumpslazydog', 'animals']], dtype='<U25')
```

Instead of the array with the spaces in between the words:

```
norm_corpus= array([['sky blue beautiful', 'weather'],
       ['love blue beautiful sky', 'weather'],
       ['quick brown fox jumps lazy dog', 'animals']], dtype='<U25')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change `doc=''.join(filtered_tokens)` to `doc=' '.join(filtered_tokens)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `doc=' '.join(filtered_tokens)` just by adding a space because you didnt define any things for the tokens.